# How to invoke a JS function only when a condition is met

Tags: javascript

I have a dropdown list called "location" that needs to be closed when I clicked either to the navbar or header container. So far, I could not create the right condition to this case. I added my codepen for reference ..https://codepen.io/Joselle24/pen/dyNbzKY.... Need some help..Thank you so much

```
<nav id="mainnavbar" onload="myNaveffect()">
      <!--3 divs-->
  <div class="imageicon">
    <a href="index.html"><img src="images/brandlogo2.png" alt="brandlogo" width="50px" height="50px"></a>
    <a href="index.html" class="brandtitle" alt="brandtitle">Website Name</a>
  </div>

  <div class="navbarlink_uno">
    <ul>
      <li onclick="myLocfunction()" class="dropbtn">
        <a target="_blank" style="padding-right: 2%;"> Locations</a>
        <i class="arrow down"></i>
      </li>
      <div class="locdropdown_container">
        <a href="#" class="">Restaurant</a>
        <a href="navbarlinks/location/pbkbar/index_pbkbar.html">PBK Mini Bar</a>
      </div>

      <li class="menu"><a href="navbarlinks/menu/index_menu_seasonal.html" target="_self" class="links">Menu</a></li>
      <li class="story"><a href="navbarlinks/story/index_story.html" target="_self" class="links">Story</a></li>
      <li class="gallery"><a href="navbarlinks/gallery/index_gallery.html" target="_self" class="links">Gallery</a></li>
      <li class="rewards"><a href="navbarlinks/rewards/index_rewards.html" target="_self" class="links">Rewards</a></li>
      <li class="donate"><a href="navbarlinks/donate/index_donate.html" target="_self" class="links">Donate</a></li>
      <li class="orderbtn"><a href="navbarlinks/order/index_order.html" target="_self">Order Pickup & Delivery</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="burgernavbar">
    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
  </div>
</nav>

  
<header>
    
</header>
```

Here is my JS

```
/* LOCATION FINDER TAB DROPDOWN BUTTON */
/* LOCATION FINDER TAB DROPDOWN BUTTON */

   //function to add ".show" selector to display "locdropdown_container" mini-container*/  
function myLocfunction() { 
    let xr = document.getElementsByClassName("locdropdown_container");
    xr[0].classList.toggle("show");  //we use the toggle()method, because it make the "class" selector on/off
};  

   //function to remove ".show" selector */
function closelocbtn(){
  const locbodyclose = document.getElementsByClassName("locdropdown_container");
        locbodyclose[0].classList.remove("show");  //we use the remove()method, because it makes the toggle()method functionable after invoking the remove()method
};  
    
  //loop all parent container after nav container*/    
let locx1, locx2;

// locx1 = document.querySelectorAll("nav, header"); //did not work
locx1 = document.querySelectorAll("nav ~ header"); //selects all element after nav container


  for (locx2 = 0; locx2 < locx1.length; locx2++) {   //loop all element
       locx1[locx2].addEventListener("click", closelocbtn);  //add an event listener and a function
};


//problem: need to invoke the function closelocbtn(), also to nav container with id#mainnavbar when the "classList.toogle" is active/on  


 /*Tested and did not work:*/
var demoss =document.querySelectorAll("#mainnavbar");  //added for selection

//var dddd = document.querySelectorAll(".show");  //store the class selector .show. 

//or

var dddd =  xr[0].classList.toggle("show");
 if (dddd == true){ //what i when here is when the .show class is selected the var demoss will execute the closelocbtn().
      demoss[0].addEventListener("click", closelocbtn);  //added
    };
```

Comment: You could use the `.contains` function on the `classList` to check if it has the `show` class. Like `elm.classList.contains('show')`. inside the `closelocbtn` function

Comment: I did that, unfortunately it did not work.. I think the problem here is about the the variable "locx1" which selects the "nav" and "header" tag for the close function and it includes its child elements inside. I wonder if there's a DOM method or property that would exclude the child elements when selecting the parent. Or if you could help me creating a condition, that works like ,,, we can only invoke or execute the "closelocbtn" function only or later when the "myLocfunction" function is invoke first. This way we could now select any element aside from the header.. Thank you .

Answer (score 2):

> need to invoke the function closelocbtn(), also to nav container with id#mainnavbar when the "classList.toogle" is active/on

I changed the selector string you were using to select either the `#mainnavbar` or the `header` beside `nav`

```js
let locx1 = [...document.querySelectorAll("#mainnavbar, nav ~ header")];
const myLocfunction = () => document.querySelector(".locdropdown_container").classList.toggle("show");
const closelocbtn = () => document.querySelector(".locdropdown_container").classList.remove("show");

locx1.forEach(elm => elm.addEventListener('click', closelocbtn));
```

Comment: Hi @a.mola, i've updated by comment,, I think im having an issue with condition. i only i can create a condition that would works like ,, when function1 is invokes then the function2 or closing function could now work,

Comment: Lets continue this discussion in chat https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230716/how-to-invoke-a-js-function-only-when-a-condition-is-met

Answer (score 0):

Hi found the answer to this task,,thank you ..

```
function myLocfunction(event){  document.querySelector(".locdropdown_container").classList.toggle("show");
      myLocfunction.called = true;
        event.stopPropagation();
};

function closelocbtn(){
  if(myLocfunction.called){
      document.querySelector(".locdropdown_container").classList.remove("show");
  }
}
```